# How do I perform a minimax ($L^\infty$) regression?

Tags: regression

I will confine my question to the simple case of constructing a linear fit of one independent variable $X$ and one dependent variable $Y$, with no intercept term.

The sample predictions are $\hat y_i = \beta x_i$. Define the $p$-norm as

$$L^p = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \vert y_i - \hat y_i \vert^p \right)^\frac{1}{p}$$

And define the $L^p$-regression of a sample $\lbrace x_i, y_i\rbrace_{i=1}^n$  as  $\beta$ such that $L^p$ is minimized.

I know how to do a least-squares ($L^2$) regression by solving the normal equations. I have also seen a linear programming procedure that does $L^1$ regression (minimizes the mean absolute error). And in the general case, you can define a reasonable search space and use numeric methods to find $\beta$ for arbitrary $p$.

**I am wondering about the $p=\infty$ case.** It can be shown that

$$L^\infty = \max \lbrace \vert y_i - \hat y_i \vert \rbrace$$

so an $L^\infty$ regression would amount to **finding the value of $\beta$ that minimizes the maximum error.**

Can this be solved explicitly, or do I need to use numeric methods?

Comment: The chosen answer answers my question, although the question doesn't ask my question. The software recommendations are also a little dated.

Comment: I’ve thought about doing. This in Keras. That might be overkill, but you could give a linear regression as a simple neural net that has no hidden layers. I have wondered why I want to do this, though, other than just to see what happens, so I am very curious to hear your answer: why use this loss function?

Comment: Well, I was going to ask about use cases as a separate question :) Perhaps there would be an application in some form of sports betting, where you are penalized based on your worst guess.